# What is best way to auto-fix all orphaned user accounts in all SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server

A DBA consultant provided us with the following SQL script several years ago.  It still works but SQL prompt reports that `[master].[dbo].[syslogins]` is depreciated.  My question is, what replaces `[syslogins]` in SQL Server 2019 and/or is there a better process for fixing orphaned users in all databases? Here's the script we use:

```
    DECLARE @UserCount INT
    DECLARE @UserCurr INT
    DECLARE @userName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @vsql NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @Users TABLE
        (
        id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        userName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
        )
    INSERT INTO @Users(UserName) 
    SELECT 
        [name] 
    FROM 
        [master].[dbo].[syslogins] --depreciated?
    SELECT
        @UserCount = MAX([id])
    FROM
        @Users

    SET @UserCurr = 1

    WHILE(@UserCurr <= @UserCount)

        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @userName = [userName]
            FROM
                @Users
            WHERE [id] = @UserCurr
            SET @vsql = '[dbo].[sp_change_users_login] ''AUTO_FIX'',''' + @userName + ''''
            EXEC (@vsql)

            SET @UserCurr = @UserCurr + 1
        END
```

I've searched for other solutions but none seem better than what we're already using.  If our script is referencing a depreciated table though, I'd like to update the code.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend https://dba.stackexchange.com/ for when you've passed out of the realm of regular programming.

Comment: On your question `what replaces [syslogins] in SQL Server 2019`, Please refer to [Mapping System Tables to System Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel.  That was the answer I was looking for.